# If f' is Lipschitz, what about f?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Let $\|F'(\boldsymbol{\beta_1})-F'(\boldsymbol{\beta_2})\|_2 \leq M \|
\boldsymbol{\beta_1}-\boldsymbol{\beta_2} \| _2,$ $\forall
\boldsymbol{\beta_1},\boldsymbol{\beta_2} \in
\overline{S(\boldsymbol{\beta}^*,\delta)},$ where
\begin{equation}\overline{S(\boldsymbol{\beta}^*,\delta)}= \{ \boldsymbol{\beta}
: \| \boldsymbol{\beta}^*-\boldsymbol{\beta} \|_2 \leq \delta
\},\end{equation} and $\delta>0$. $\boldsymbol{\beta}^*$ is just the solution of the system $F(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ and $F'$ is its jacobian matrix. So $F'$ is Lipschitz. How can we prove that it holds:

$F(\boldsymbol{\beta})=F'(\boldsymbol{\beta})(\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\beta}^*)+O(\|e\|_2^2)$ where $\|e\|=\boldsymbol{\beta}-\boldsymbol{\beta}^*$ ?

Comment: the system is $F(\beta)=0$ of course...

Comment: Mean Value Theorem: $F(\beta)=F'(\gamma)(\beta-\beta^*) =F'(\beta)(\beta-\beta^*)+(F'(\gamma)-F'(\beta)(\beta-\beta^*)$. Where $\gamma$ is between $\beta$ and $\beta^*$.